# Is there a way to completely cover a complex area in divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a little project with html, css and javascript(jQuery). Basically, I have an svg (which is a blank map of the world) and I want to cover every part of that image (or basically it would be enough to just cover the part of the  webpage which the image occupies but that's not as precise) with multiples of  a div (which is a small circle) that I created. In other words, I want to cover every country on the blank-map image in those circles and later do an animation. Is there a way to do that automatically, without having to copy-paste the div each time to make a new div with different coordinates (since that's what I did so far). Plus, since I positioned all my divs using coordinates, they are obviously not in the same part of my svg when the webpage is open in a minimised screen as when in full screen (since technically the divs aren't even placed **on** the actual image, but rather on the body **over** my image). Is there a better way to do this as well (place divs **on the image its-self** and make them stay in the same area of the image regardless of the window size?) I'm pretty much new to all this so I know that my code is definitely not the best and that it can all be done in a better way, plus it's been years since I last did any web design.

Additionally, those circle divs move to a random location on hover, which can be seen in the js/jQuery below. This part works fine but I understand that I might have to change it depending on how I change my css/html.

You can find all the parts of my code bellow and I apologize in advance if you find the code absolutely terrible, I know it can all be done in a much better way.

Here is the js fiddle which kinda sums it up (just like on the code snippet below, the image is different than my own and is not an svg here, so the circle-divs are placed in wrong locations, they are properly placed on a part of the map in my original file): https://jsfiddle.net/xoypvnmc/
---and a full-screen version: https://jsfiddle.net/xoypvnmc/show

Thank you all in advance, and if you have any questions about my project or need any additional information, please ask!

```js
$('.circles').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var maxX = $(window).width() - $(this).width();
  var maxY = $(window).height() - $(this).height();
  $(this).css({
    'left': getRandomInt(0, maxX),
    'top': getRandomInt(0, maxY)
  });
});

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ECF9F9;
}

.circles {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: cadetblue;
}

#circle1 {left:1104px; top:301px; background: tomato;}
#circle2 {left:529px; top:301px;}
#circle3 {left:517px; top:301px;}
#circle4 {left:505px; top:301px;}
#circle5 {left:493px; top:301px;}
#circle6 {left:481px; top:301px;}
#circle7 {left:469px; top:301px;}
#circle8 {left:457px; top:301px;}
#circle9 {left:445px; top:301px;}
#circle10 {left:433px; top:301px;}
#circle11 {left:421px; top:301px;}
#circle12 {left:409px; top:301px;}
#circle13 {left:397px; top:301px;}
#circle14 {left:385px; top:301px;}
#circle15 {left:373px; top:301px;}
#circle16 {left:361px; top:301px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="circles" id="circle1"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle2"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle3"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle4"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle5"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle6"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle7"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle8"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle9"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle10"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle11"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle12"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle13"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle14"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle15"></div>
  <div class="circles" id="circle16"></div>

  <img width="100%" height="100%" id="pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/31/81/0e31812689ecf1158cd5ed43a79f636b.gif" </img>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the circle divs with their position styles inline with JavaScript and add them to a div on the page that way.

```
document.getElementById("circles").innerHTML = htmlToAdd;
```

And you can position the circles relative to the image rather than the page as a whole by adding a relative container that shrinks to fit the image and tossing the circles in there as well. Your whole code will look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:#ECF9F9; 
            }
            img{
                width:100%;
            }
            #mapContainer{
                position:relative;
                display:inline-block;
                width:50%;
            }
            .circles{
                position: absolute;
                transition: all 2s;
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background:cadetblue;
            }
            #circle1 {background: tomato;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function generateCircles(circleCount){
                var htmlToAdd = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < circleCount; i++){
                    var maxCirclesPerRow = Math.floor($("#mapContainer").width() / 12);
                    var row = Math.floor(i / maxCirclesPerRow);
                    var top = row * 12;
                    var right = (i - (row * maxCirclesPerRow)) * 12;

                    htmlToAdd += "<div class=\"circles\" id=\"circle" + (i + 1) + "\" style=\"top:" + top + ";right:" + right + "px;\"></div>";
                }
                document.getElementById("circles").innerHTML = htmlToAdd;

                $('.circles').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                    var maxX = $("#mapContainer").width() - $(this).width();
                    var maxY = $("#mapContainer").height() - $(this).height();
                    $(this).css({
                        'right': getRandomInt(0, maxX),
                        'top': getRandomInt(0, maxY)
                    });
                });
            }


            function getRandomInt(min, max){
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="generateCircles(200);">
        <div id="mapContainer">
            <img id="pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/31/81/0e31812689ecf1158cd5ed43a79f636b.gif"</img>
            <div id="circles"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've added a bit of math to position the circles dynamically on the map, so you can pass whatever number of circles you want to the genereateCircles function. I've passed `200` in my example code for you. If you need an explanation of any part in particular, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I implemented parts of your code into my project and edited it up a bit to get the visual representation just right. Basically what I did is I took the circle generator you made (which makes horizontal lines of circles) and made a grid of circles which completely covers a rectangular area around and over my image. I was just wondering if there was a way for me to manipulate this code so that it can subtract all the circles which are not over the map, but on the 'white space' of the container. I know how to do this manually, but that would take a bit of time.

Comment: ++ What I mean is, could I somehow automatically include which areas I don't want  any circles in, in the circle generator its-self? I know that that would be complicated since I would probably have to make multiple circle-generating functions for different areas. So if it truly is complicated, don't waste your time  trying to help me, I will just do it all manually in the end. Thank you so much for all the help you've already given me!

Comment: No problem! Sorry, I don't think there's a super easy way to exclude certain areas. Others are welcome to chime in if they want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a system and somekind of database you could then setup those marker on the map by simple adding new object and drag that object to your marker, that will create a cordinates that could be saved to your database.

And then use these object with cordinates to create your mapp and dots.

Here is a simple example of what i mean

Make sure to look at `mappcontainer` this will solve the problem for your diffrent types of screen size.

```js
$(".circles").draggable({
containment: "parent",
drag: function( event, ui ) {
    var x =  ui.position.left;
    var y = ui.position.top;
    console.clear();
    /// those cordinates will be saved to your database with x and y
    console.log({ x:x,y:y })
  }

});
```

```css
.circles {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.mappcontainer{
position:relative;
width:600px;
height:400px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<p> Drag that marker too your cordinate </p>
<div class="mappcontainer">
<div class="circles"></div>
<img width="100%" height="100%" id="pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/31/81/0e31812689ecf1158cd5ed43a79f636b.gif" </img>


</div>
```

I hop you undesrtood the idee, you could comment and ask otherwise

> Update
>   For the db you need to use something like C# or PHP to get the data from the server.

Ok see the example below after you have got the data from the database will will get a list of cordinates in json.

See example below on how you will build the codinates, as mention this is only an exampe and not the whole solution

```js
/// those data you get from the database, that you have setup on the prev example
var listOfCordinates = [{
  "x": 200,
  "y": 23
}, 
{
  "x": 66.00001525878906,
  "y": 51.00000190734863
}]

listOfCordinates.forEach((cor)=>{ 
$(".mappcontainer").append($("<div class='circles'></div>").css({left:cor.x, top:cor.y}))
})
```

```css
.circles {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 2s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: cadetblue;
}

.mappcontainer{
position:relative;
width:600px;
height:400px;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mappcontainer">
<img width="100%" height="100%" id="pic" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0e/31/81/0e31812689ecf1158cd5ed43a79f636b.gif" </img>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Alen.Toma! Firstly, thank you very much for responding! I reviewed your answer and very much like the idea. However, since I've never used a system/database to manipulate web design in that way, I must admit that I'm not quite sure what you meant by that. So do you maybe have a suggestion or an example of how exactly the system and database you mentioned should be implemented (so basically how can get the window showing coordinates on my local device)? Again, I apologise that I'm not that familiar with all this and that I didn't fully understand it. Once more, thanks for answering!